# Add Reference Library to an outside MS Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a code that creates new MS Access Databases. I'd like to add reference libraries to these newly created MS Access Databases.
Here is the code that I wrote but is not working:

```
Sub makeDb(fl As String)    
Dim fs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'check if the file already exists

If fs.FileExists(fl) = False Then

    'create new ms access database

    Dim accessApp As Access.Application
    Set accessApp = New Access.Application
    accessApp.DBEngine.CreateDatabase fl, dbLangGeneral

    'loop through all references in current database and add them to the newly created dbs

    Dim cur_vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject: Set cur_vbProj = Application.VBE.VBProjects(1)
    Dim cur_vbRefs As VBIDE.References: Set cur_vbRefs = cur_vbProj.References
    Dim cur_vbRef As VBIDE.Reference

    For Each cur_vbRef In cur_vbRefs
        Dim cur_guid As String: cur_guid = cur_vbRef.Guid
        Dim cur_major As Long: cur_major = cur_vbRef.Major
        Dim cur_minor As Long: cur_minor = cur_vbRef.Minor

        'here is the code that doesn't work

        Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject: Set vbProj = accessApp.Application.VBE.VBProjects(1)
        Dim vbRefs As VBIDE.References: Set vbRefs = vbProj.References
        vbRefs.AddFromGuid Guid:=cur_guid, Major:=cur_major, Minor:=cur_minor

    Next

    accessApp.Quit
    Set accessApp = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

The line `Set vbProj = accessApp.Application.VBE.VBProjects(1)` throws Run-Time error '9' Subscript out of range. How should I modify the code? Is it even possible to add references to an outside database?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but 1) you might try VBProjects(0) in case it's zero based, 2) you might create a template database ahead of time (set up with references as needed), and copy the template database instead of creating a new one

Comment: Alternative is to modify code to use late binding then don't need to select libraries.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you creating Access database projects on the fly? If needing to distribute copies of FrontEnds with same application code (with libraries), why not just copy current Access database at file system level?

Comment: I need it because it's work requirement. Ppl can't use SAS EG that would handle big datasets way better. They want me to put data into MS Access. If I just copy over last months database as suggested, I then need to empty all tables, and compact the database. That's the solution I am currently using but I don't like it. I am looking for better alternatives.

Comment: Why not have multiple months in same database?

Comment: Because I work for health insurance company and MS Access can hold only 2 GB of data. That's about good enough for one month. As I said, MS Access is not the right tool for what I do but unfortunately, not everyone can use SAS EG or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
Sub makeDb(f1 As String)
Dim accApp As Access.Application
Dim cur_vbRefs As References
Dim cur_vbRef As Reference
If Dir(f1) = "" Then
    Access.DBEngine.CreateDatabase f1, dbLangGeneral
    Set accApp = New Access.Application
    accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase f1
    'loop through all references in current database and add them to the newly created dbs
    Set cur_vbRefs = Application.References
    For Each cur_vbRef In cur_vbRefs
        On Error Resume Next
        accApp.References.AddFromGuid cur_vbRef.Guid, cur_vbRef.Major, cur_vbRef.Minor
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: worked. how would you make the new database trusted?

Comment: Topic for another question. I've never explored VBA for this.